# How to connect and create a database in MySQL?

Tags: kubuntu, mysql, database

I want to install MySQL and create a database on it using the following code:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
mysqladmin -h localhost -u {username} -p create lrs
```

I get the following message after executing the second line:

```
    Enter password:
    mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
    error: 'Access denied for user '{username}'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

What is the problem?

Comment: If you actually used these 2 commands where did you GRANT PRIVILIGES for {username} (if not admin/root) to be able to access a database?

Answer (score 31):

After you've installed MySQL, you need to **set mysql root password**. To do so:

1. Enter the next command in a terminal:

   `mysql -u root`
2. Now it should open the *mysql* console. And type the following line:

   `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('yourpassword');`

To exit from the *mysql* console enter `exit`.

Now you should **create the database** with the *root* user. To do so:

1. Open *mysql* from terminal:

   `mysql -u root -p`
2. Enter the password created before.
3. Enter the following line:

   `CREATE DATABASE yourdatabasename;`

If you enter `SHOW DATABASES;` you should see it in the list. If so, you have a database ready to use!

Comment: `mysql -u root` gives me `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: That error means that you already have a `root` user and it has a password. If you forgot the `root` password, read [the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix).

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to MySQL using the root user and associated password. If you need to set them, use the following command: `sudo mysqladmin -u root -h localhost password 'mypassword'`

From there, you can configure additional accounts by following this document: [How to Create a New User and Grant Permissions in MySQL](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql)

Comment: I copied the `sudo mysqladmin -u root -h localhost password 'mypassword'`and pasted it into my terminal and I get the message `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`.

Comment: @Bert This code will not work. The `password 'mypassword'` is wrong, it should be `-password 'mypassword'`

Comment: should something be replaced with 'mypassword'?

Comment: I executed `sudo mysqladmin -u root -h localhost -password 'mypassword'`, but I get `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

Comment: @user543489 What happens if you enter `mysql -u root`?

Answer (score 1):

This is strange because since 12.04 (guessing you're running Kubuntu 12.04), MySQL has been default. Looks like you're missing a few steps in between, so let's look over this:

First, as you mentioned, let's do an installation,

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

After you installed it, let's try a little test,

```
sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
```

When you run this, you should see this reply,

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                LISTEN      2556/mysqld
```

If this is not running correctly, run this restart command,

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

**Now to configure the server.**

Let's go to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to configure the basic settings. This includes the Log File, Port Number, Etc. For example, to configure MySQL to listen for connections from network hosts, change the *bind-address* directive to the server's IP address:

```
bind-address            = 192.168.0.5
```

After this, restart the MySQL daemon,

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

If you want to change the MySQL root password, run this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

The daemon will be stopped and you'll be prompted for a new password.

Once you're done, you should be configured and a few google searches will teach you how to create a database

Source: [The Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/mysql.html)

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

(5.5 is the version number, adapt if you have a different version)

This will allow you to set your MySQL root password, that you can then use with `mysqladmin` and `mysql` commands.

Answer (score -1):

After you've installed MySQL, you need to set mysql root password. To do so:

```
Enter the next command in a terminal:

mysql -u root -p

Enter Password: (Enter your password here).
```

Comment: This doesn't contribute anything that hasn't already been said in the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is 3 years old but I just had this problem as well and wanted to post my answer in case anyone else does the same search I did.

`mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed`

This indicates that your user doesn't have permission to connect to the database itself, before it even gets to logging in; not the database user, your actual linux user.  Run everything as super user: sudo mysql -u root -p

Only root (the linux user, or a user with sudo privileges) can log in to mysql as root (the database user).  I wasn't able to find anywhere documenting this but experimentation proved it was the case.  You can create a new user with all the same rights as the root user and that will not be restricted.

```
sudo mysql -u root
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('yourpassword');
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now "newuser" (or whatever name you choose) can be logged-in-as without the need for sudo and you can use it for all your database administrative needs.

Comment: Using the word `probably` in an answer here is frowned upon.

Comment: Well I certainly can't say that it is without testing it, now can I?