# accessing MySQL using terminal in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: command-line, server, mysql

accessing phpmyadmin db from terminal now in ubuntu 13.04 i firstly installed mysql server with
`sudo apt-get install mysql-server` mysql server version 5.5  now in terminal i can check if it is working by

```
sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
```

it responds me by prompting me for password and then

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN             26214/mysqld
```

but to connect using my root account i typed `mysql -u root -p`  prompting for password it shows
`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

when i try this `/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p` it ask for password and says
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)`

what is there in /etc/mysql/my.cnf
and what is in `/opt/lampp/bin/mysql`

any solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried setting up password for root soon after installing MySQL?? If not first try to Enter the command in a terminal below;

```
mysql -u root
```

Now it should open the mysql console. And type the following line:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('yourpassword');
```

To exit from the mysql console enter `exit`.

Then try reconnecting with following line;

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Try the password you've entered.

**Source:** [How to connect and create a database in MySQL?](https://askubuntu.com/a/271366/179042)

Comment: but when i again try to connect by `mysql -u root -p` its showing `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: this error came after try the above steps??

Comment: yes. could not open phpmyadmin from localhost xampp.

Comment: @AzkerM  I got the same error `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' `

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya - Would you please elaborate this with a new question referencing this post or any other steps you have tried.. and with few more information. A single comment will not help to track down the cause. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the following command

```
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

Then Enter
after that it requires enter password if you have changed the password of root than type this password otherwise simply press Enter keeping it blank.

Comment: This solves the above error `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

Answer (score 0):

yes man.after i followed those steps i was able to connect to phpmyadmin from terminal but after a restart i see i cant access phpmyadmin from localhost

`#2002 - No such file or directory
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)`
and also status from localhost shwing mysql database deactivated . all other like SSI,PHP,CGI is activated.
in security section its howing phpmyadmin as unknown and mysql user root no password unknown.

before it was all activated and secured i have done that to set password for root and localhost with all preveiledged when i installed xampp in linux.  my `config.inc.php` file.location `/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin`

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '$5hfhjfhgst5fg4%43(*&'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A     MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */


/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'wtf11111';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

In `my.cnf` located in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

`[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0`

`[mysqld]
  #
  # * Basic Settings
   #
  user      = mysql
  pid-file  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
  socket        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  port      = 3306
  basedir       = /usr
  datadir       = /var/lib/mysql
  tmpdir        = /tmp
  lc-messages-dir   = /usr/share/mysql
  skip-external-locking`

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the password for the MySQL by login to the safe mode.

Stop the MySQL service by using the below command.

> /etc/init.d/mysql stop

Then start the MySQL using in the safe mode

> mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

Once login to the MySQL using the safe mode, please execute the below command to update the password.

> UPDATE user SET Password=password('MySQL_PWD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
>
> `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY "MySQL_PWD" WITH GRANT OPTION;`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

After executing the above command kill the mysqld and start the MySQL.

Now try login to the MySQL with the updated password.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root
```

and then use

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('yourpassword');
```

to set your password and then use ctrl + c or use exit to logout from `mysql` then use

```
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

and type password (password is hidden )
and `ENTER` then 
enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Your installation is correct. Make sure you enter the password in the root account and not in your local account.
To switch to root account, in the terminal type "sudo -i" and now you'll get the root user privileges.
Now enter "mysql -u root -p" and the password , it will surely work for you.